# DropdownMenu not aligned to width of Textfield in Dialog composable

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, android-jetpack-compose, android-dialog, android-menu

The `DropdownMenu` composable is not aligning to the width of the `OutlinedTextField` which is inside a `Dialog` composable. It is shifted slightly to the right. However, placing the `DropdownMenu` outside the `Dialog` composable works fine. How can I fix this?

[image]

**DropdownMenu Composable**

```
@Composable
fun MyDropdownMenu() {
    var mExpanded = rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var mSelectedText = rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
    var mTextFieldSize = remember { mutableStateOf(Size.Zero) }
    val mCategories = listOf(
        "Produce",
        "Bakery",
        "Meats",
        "Dairy",
        "Deli",
        "Beverages",
        "Frozen"
    )
    val icon = if (mExpanded.value)
        Icons.Filled.KeyboardArrowUp
    else
        Icons.Filled.KeyboardArrowDown
    Column {

        Box {
            OutlinedTextField(
                value = mSelectedText.value,
                readOnly = true,
                onValueChange = { mSelectedText.value = it },
                label = { Text(text = "Category") },
                trailingIcon = {
                    Icon(icon, null,
                        Modifier.clickable { mExpanded.value = !mExpanded.value })
                },
                modifier = Modifier.onGloballyPositioned { coordinates ->
                mTextFieldSize.value = coordinates.size.toSize()
            }.fillMaxWidth(),
            )

            DropdownMenu(
                expanded = mExpanded.value,
                onDismissRequest = { mExpanded.value = false },
                modifier =  Modifier
                      .width(with(LocalDensity.current) { mTextFieldSize.value.width.toDp()})
            ) {
                mCategories.forEach { label ->
                    DropdownMenuItem(onClick = {
                        mSelectedText.value = label
                        mExpanded.value = false
                    }) {
                        Text(text = label)
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }


}
```

**Dialog Composable**

```
@Composable
fun AddItemDialog(
    onConfirmClicked: () -> Unit,
    onDismiss: () -> Unit,
) {
    Dialog(
        onDismissRequest = onDismiss
    ) {
        Surface(
            shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.medium,
            color = MaterialTheme.colors.surface,
            modifier = Modifier
                .requiredWidth(LocalConfiguration.current.screenWidthDp.dp * 0.96f)
                .padding(4.dp)
        ) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(top = 16.dp, bottom = 0.dp, start = 16.dp, end = 16.dp)
            ) {
                Text(text = "Add an item", style = MaterialTheme.typography.subtitle1)

                MyDropdownMenu()
                
                Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.End) {
                    TextButton(onClick = onDismiss) {
                        Text(text = "Cancel")
                    }
                    TextButton(onClick = onConfirmClicked) {
                        Text(text = "OK")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems they both have the same width. The problem could be that DropdownMenu is not centered (you can try to center it with outside Box)

Comment: This is governed by the `PopupPositionProvider`, specifically `DropdownMenuPositionProvider` - I'd try and see what values it has for input, and the calculated position. This might get called several times as you manipulate its width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bug is related to the fact that you're trying to force Dialog to be bigger than it's expected with `Modifier.requiredWidth`. Visually it works, but `DropdownMenu` uses alert window size to layout, and this size is smaller than your drawn view.

There is actually another way to make the dialog view take up the entire width (except for a small padding) that does not cause this bug:

```
Dialog(
    onDismissRequest = {  },
    properties = DialogProperties(usePlatformDefaultWidth = false),
) {
```